# assigning items of a list to a new list of the same type but with an added property

Tags: c#, list

I have list of type `Notification`. I also have a type of `NotificationWithScore`.

Notification With Score looks like:

```
public class NotificationWithScore
    {
        public Notification Notification { get; set; }
        public int Score { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to create a new list of type `NotificationWithScore` using the existing notification list I already have and provide a default score of 0.

when I go to create a `List<NotificationWithScore> n = new List<NotificationWithScore>();`

I can only assign them individually using a foreach. Is there a way to do this in Linq?

Comment: so what is stopping you?

Comment: " can only assign them individually using a foreach. Is there a way to do this in Linq?" Sure you can, but be aware that linq will internally also loop your list anyway, so there´s no difference between a classic loop and the appropriate linq-code apart from a different syntax.

Comment: @HimBromBeere that's a good point. The main reason I want to use linq is so it's easier to read, fortunately performance isn't an issue with the program I am creating.

Comment: From my experience "is easier to read" is fairly opion-based. Quite often linq-code is even harder to read and a good old-style loop will make it clearer to readers of your code to understand. So be careful and don´t replace every single loop by linq only because you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LINQ

```
List<NotificationWithScore> AddScore(List<Notification> list)
{
    return list.Select(n => new NotificationWithScore { Notification = n, Score = 0 }).ToList();
}
```